# ($(window).width() > 768) NOT breaking at 768px

Tags: jquery

The problem is that the breakpoint seems to be 783px and not at 768px like I specified in my if-statement.

Since I use Bootstrap I need to provide some code based on Bootstraps breakpoints. I've tried innerWidth as well but it doesn't work. Media queries is not an option either since I need to use JavaScript to change the DOM. It has to be jQuery as well since that's what we use at the company I work for. See example code below:

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
   $("#search").insertAfter(".search-webb");
   $("#pages").insertAfter(".page-webb");
}else {
   $("#search").insertAfter(".search-mobile");
   $("#pages").insertAfter(".page-mobile");
}
```

Comment: Where is this code placed inside your script? Why not add an event listener to the window for a resize and then place this code inside of the event callback?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint there when you suspect that the width is now greater than 768 -> to verify? It is undoubtedly that the width api is returning a different pixel width than you suspect it should be. But the question is, "why is there a disconnect. What are you using to determine that the window is at 782 pixels, while still not going into the if clause?

Comment: I tested this by using this page with the dev tools. When I resize the dev tools, it reports in the top right a width of 958 pixels, but then posting `$(window).width()` in the console displays 1046 pixels width. So the width API is considering something else in its width.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap then you're *already using media queries* - so time to talk your department into upgrading by showing them how much more efficient and effective it is to let the browser do this natively.

Comment: window.innerWidth you don't need jquery there, it doesn't HAVE to be jquery plain old javascript is always a valid option

Comment: Bootstrap offers `hidden-*` classes which can be used to hide elements if the `*` range classes are in effect.  So rather than dynamically inserting elements with javascript, you can make them be there, but hide them when they should not be displayed.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements  Looks like it's not `hidden-*` anymore, but the same concept still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll-bar that applied sometimes gave me trouble. Had to solve it like this:

`(window).matchMedia("(min-width: 767.98px)").matches`

Works like a charm.